How to convert pairwise dissimilarity matrix into continues predictor in R
I have collected plant species data and AGB from 25 different sites and I want to do regression analysis of Beta-diversity (i.e. dissimilarity among 25 sites) as a predictor and  AGB as response variable. I have done the Jaccard dissimilarities in species composition among the 25 sites using Beta.part package. However, I get a matrix of dissimilarity, but I want to convert the dissimilarity data matrix into continues predictor to do the regression analysis in R. How can I convert the pairwise dissimilarity matrix into continues predictor? Your help would be highly appreciated!
